# preprocess_input changes array inplace, but doesn't change tensor

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0, tf.keras

I've noticed some strange behaviour in `preprocess_input`, a function used to preprocess images to normalise values correctly for the specific pre-trained network you are using.
After several hours of debugging, it appears that when a tensor is used as an input, the input tensor is unmodified, and it returns the processed input as a new tensor:

```
tensor = tf.ones(3)*100
print(tensor)
tensor2 = tf.keras.applications.mobilenet_v2.preprocess_input (tensor)
print(tensor)
print(tensor2)
```

returns

```
tf.Tensor([100. 100. 100.], shape=(3,), dtype=float32)
tf.Tensor([100. 100. 100.], shape=(3,), dtype=float32)
tf.Tensor([-0.21568626 -0.21568626 -0.21568626], shape=(3,), dtype=float32)
```

However when doing the exact same thing but with a numpy array as input, apart from returning the processed version as a new array, *the original array is changed to be the same as the new array*:

```
array = np.ones(3)*100
print(array)
array2 = tf.keras.applications.mobilenet_v2.preprocess_input (array)
print(array)
print(array2)
array+=1
print(array)
print(array2)
```

returns

```
[100. 100. 100.]
[-0.21568627 -0.21568627 -0.21568627]       # <== input has changed!!!
[-0.21568627 -0.21568627 -0.21568627]
[0.78431373 0.78431373 0.78431373]
[0.78431373 0.78431373 0.78431373]          # <== further changes to input change output
```

Three questions:

1. Why is behaviour not uniform?
2. Why is it considered beneficial for the original array to be changed?
3. Why does preprocess_input both return the new values and also modify in-place - isn't it usually one or the other, doing both is confusing...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be fair the [docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/applications/mobilenet_v2/preprocess_input) do mention this behaviour:

> The preprocessed data are written over the input data if the data
> types are compatible. To avoid this behaviour, numpy.copy(x) can be
> used.

So that kind of answers Q1 - tensors are immutable, so can't be overwritten, as opposed to np arrays which are mutable so can be changed in-place.

Note: this isn't a great answer - if this function will be used a lot on tensors, surely its behaviour should be fixed such that even on arrays it will behave the same. I.e. it shouldn't *ever* change the input, so it behaves uniformly and people will know what to expect.